# Is there a second encounter with Trevor's Mother?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

So I found the Deludamol Van outside a hospital in LS, drove it back to Trevor's house for her mother but her mother isn't there anymore.

Now this is apparently "The first encounter" pointed out on the [IGN GTA5 Wiki](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Mrs._Philips)

The second encounter for the wiki says "Please check back later"

Since the main storyline is done I really want some closure (if any) for Trevor's Mom. Does anyone know if the story continues or this "second encounter" doesn't exist?

Comment: How about not putting information like that in the title...

Comment: Please do not write questions with spoilers. I did not know she was even in the game and now the surprise is ruined!!! THANKS! **D-:<** *(very angry/upset face)*

Answer (score 2):

[Multiple](http://gta.wikia.com/Mrs._Philips) [sources](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Mrs_Philips) [indicate](http://gtaforums.com/topic/622220-mrs-phillips/) that

> Trevor's mom never appears again after the mission you mentioned.